# IOS app in swift 3 not navigating to further viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I am doing project on secured authentication....when i try to register my email id and password it is not going to next viewcontroller...when i run my code it is working well and not showing any errors but i am not getting output...here is my code

```
 @IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // TODO: Do some form validation on the email and password


    if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text {

        // Check if it's sign in or register
        if isSignIn {
            // Sign in the user with Firebase
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

                // Check that user isn't nil
                if let u = user {
                    // User is found, go to home screen
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    // Error: check error and show message
                    self.displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: "Password didn't match");
                }


            })

        }
        else {
            // Register the user with Firebase

            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

                // Check that user isn't nil
                if let u = user {
                    // User is found, go to home screen
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToEnroll", sender: self)

                }
                else {
                    // Error: check error and show message
                }
            })

        }

    }
```

Comment: could you add Else part for Outer If (textfield check). may be control terminate on first if and you are not handled it. just put else part with some print message

Answer (score 0):

Please check the connection in Storyboard, make sure that the segue name of link between Current VC -> Home VC is: "goToHome"
Check the same for Enroll VC

Comment: Thank you ....but my register button sometimes it is working and sometimes it is not working....is there any change in the code which i want to make?

Comment: You should check again about FireBase, I remember that optimize the connection in Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Check here if the idenfier is same as you have given in your story board.

Note: Please check first that the identifier you have mentioned here is same as your storyboard one.

Comment: func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToHome"
        {
            if let objViewController2 = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
                
                objViewController2.str = emailId
            }
        }
    }